# Simplified proof of: totally categorical theories are pseudofinite

Tags: logic, model-theory

It is a very well known result (I guess attributed originally to Zilber and later extended by Cherlin-Harrington-Lachlan) that every totally categorical theory is pseudofinite.

However, the papers usually go through several technical lemmas to obtain not only this result but also several others.

My question is:

> Does anyone know a simplified proof that shows that every totally
>   categorical theory is pseudofinite?

Comment: 1. It would nice if you could recall the definition pseudofinite. 2. If I remember well, there is a simple proof that every $\omega$-categorical strongly minimal theory is pseudofinite. (But to generalise this to totally categorical is hard.)

Comment: @PrimoPetri A theory is pseudofinite if every sentence consistent with it has a finite model.

Comment: I see that you have created ([tag:pseudofinite-structures]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/pseudofinite-structures/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).